# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LIST in /home/public_html/gigs.html on line 12

Tags: php, arrays, list, loops, foreach

I'm trying to build an events page for my band's website using PHP to list our upcoming gigs (I'm still quite new to server side script) And I keep getting the above error displaying on the page in browser. I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing / doing wrong but I can't seem to figure out what it is (I'm struggling to find relevant info online too)

Here is my code on the html / php page

```
<?php
$body_id = 'gigs'
?>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fragments/html.html'); ?>

<div class="content-left">

    <?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/arr_gigs.php');

    foreach ($gig as list($day, $month, $year, $location, $description, $event_link, $ticket_link)) {

        echo '<span class="top">\n\t';
        if ($ticket_link = true){
            echo '<a href="$ticket_link" onClick="return false;"> BOOK TICKETS </a>\n';
        };
        echo '</span>\n\n';                         
        echo '<span class="bottom">\n\t';
        echo '<a href="$event_link" class="gig-tag" onClick="return false;">\n\t\t';
        echo '<span class="when">$day \/ $month - $location</span>\n\t\t';
        echo '<span class="where">$description</span>\n\t';
        echo '</a>\n';
        echo '</span>\n';
    };
?>

</div>
```

And here is php/arr_gigs.php where I hope to put in all the gig details, date, location, links etc.

```
<?php

$gig = [
[28,12,2013,
'The Firebug - Leicester', 
'with more awesome bands',
'www.facebook.com',
'www.seetickets.com'],

[19,04,2014,
'Pi Bar - Leicester', 
'(acts tbc)',
'www.facebook.com',
''],
];

?>
```

As far as I know I'm running the latest version of PHP (5.3 or similar)
If there's any help or advice someone could give me I'd be really grateful :) Or if you think there's a better way I could achieve the desired effect

Comment: first of all it seems like you are missing a ";" right at the beginning: `$body_id = 'gigs';`

Comment: Where did I go wrong? I was following the information on this page with a few embelishments http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

As I said, I'm still fairly new to PHP, I have understanding of JS, JQuery and Template Toolkit (thanks to my workplace), but I still have a lot to learn on PHP lol

Comment: `foreach($array as $key => $value)`. `$value` in this case cannot be a `list()`.

Comment: You are not using PHP 5.5 which is where that syntax is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code is not valid in PHP versions prior to 5.5 (this means you are *not* using PHP 5.5):

```
foreach ($gig as list($day, $month, $year, $location, $description, $event_link, $ticket_link)) {
```

If you wish to get all of those values either use the array syntax to access them:

```
foreach ($gig as $giginfo) {
    echo $giginfo['day'];
```

Or use a while loop:

```
while (list($day, $month, $year, $location, $description, $event_link, $ticket_link) = each($gig)) {
```

Or use `extract()` (**not recommended**):

```
foreach ($gig as $giginfo) {
    extract($giginfo);
```

As for your array, you are using a syntax that is only available in PHP 5.4. So you will need to use `array()` syntax instead:

```
<?php

$gig = array(
    array(28,12,2013,
        'The Firebug - Leicester', 
        'with more awesome bands',
        'www.facebook.com',
        'www.seetickets.com'
    ),
    array(
        19,04,2014,
        'Pi Bar - Leicester', 
        '(acts tbc)',
        'www.facebook.com',
        ''
    ),
);

?>
```

Comment: Ah right ok, I've looked into what vers I'm running and it was 5.3.24 (I didn't realise there was 5.5 lol) I'm trying to update that now within cPanel (it's being a bugger giving me a cageFS error, but it's being dealt with)

In the meantime I swapped out the foreach loop with your suggested while loop and that has the page building, but now it's failing with my actual array :( "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/public_html/php/arr_gigs.php on line 3"

I do really appreciate the help John :)

Comment: You're using an array syntax that is only available in PHP 5.4. So you will need to define that array using traditional syntax. See my updated answer.

Comment: Cheers John, that information has gotten me a lot further, I'm still having trouble extracting the gig data from the nested arrays, but I'm going to have a play and see if I can figure out how I can get the info. you can see the page as it stands here -> http://fightingeviliscool.co.uk/gigs.html (I'm getting it working functionally before sorting out the styling lol)